# Unsigned variables in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am converting some C code to Scala as we are moving (allegedly) into the Modern world here in Corporate towers, or so I have been told anyways.

Some of the C code uses unsigned variables that have a significant number of bit level (shift) operations performed upon them.

I am at a complete standstill on how to convert these to Scala, given that I believe both Scala (and Java) and indeed the JVM find unsigned types alien.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What *type* of unsigned variables in C? (e.g `char`, `int` `long`, etc)

Comment: Hi there all the operations are on unsigned with no type defined, so I assume K&R style, therefore would be ints.

Comment: The answer below is a good one, especially for scala, but just as an FYI you can up-convert to a signed long (64bit) via `long l = i & 0x00000000ffffffffL;` where `i` is the Java unsigned int. Or, if these aren't coming from an external source ... just use `long`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only difference between signed an unsigned math in C and on the JVM comes up with the right-shift operator. For unsigned math, you use *logical shift* (since you don't want sign extension), whereas for signed math you do an *arithmetic shift* (which preserves the sign). This is one of the beauties of [Two's complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Based on that, all you have to do is change the Java/Scala `>>` operator for the `>>>` operator, and you'll get the same answer, bit-by-bit. However, depending on what you're doing it might still be problematic when you try to do something with the result, e.g. if you want to print it as an unsigned integer.

Let's say you want to do some math with "unsigned" longs in Scala and print the result at the end. Just use a normal long, use the `>>>` (*logical shift*) operator in place of `>>`, and then convert it to something else at the end that can represent the unsigned value. You could use a library like suggested in @rightfold's answer, or you can just do something simple like this:

```
val x = Long.MaxValue // declare my "unsigned" long
// do some math with it ...
val y = x + 10

// Convert it to the equivalent Scala BigInt
def asUnsigned(unsignedLong: Long) =
  (BigInt(unsignedLong >>> 1) << 1) + (unsignedLong & 1)

x
// Long = 9223372036854775807
asUnsigned(y)
// res1: scala.math.BigInt = 9223372036854775817
```

If you're just using `Int`s, then you don't even have to convert to `BigInt` at the end since a `Long` can hold the answer. Just use the method that @BrianRoach suggests in his comment above to convert an `Int`'s "unsigned" value to the equivalent `Long` by masking-off the higher-order bytes. However, again, you shouldn't do the conversion until you absolutely have to. Even when using a 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit processor, the integer multiply and divide operations will be slower for a `Long` (64-bit) than for an `Int` (32-bit). (See this question for more details: [Are 64 bit integers less efficient than 32 bit integers in the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605562/1427124)).

Answer (score 8):

The JVM unfortunately does not support unsigned data types (besides `char`, thanks Erwin), but there is hope! Scala has a sufficiently advanced type system that allows you to create your own types that act like unsigned types!

There is even [a library](https://github.com/nystrom/scala-unsigned) that already does it! The library overloads the operators and provides conversions.

Comment: The JVM has one unsigned 16-bit data type: `char`. `char ch = 65535; System.out.println((int) ch);` prints `65535`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You are correct. However, if you read the comments to the question made an hour before you made this comment, the OP is talking about 32bit ints.

Comment: @BrianRoach I know the OP was, but I was responding the rightfold's statement that the JVM has no unsigned data types, which is not completely correct.