# why a uint32_t vs uint64_t speed difference?

Tags: c++, performance

Trying to understand something about how g++/cpu processes integers at runtime.

I'm measuring how long the following function takes to run:

```
template<class T>
void speedTest() {
    for(T d=0;d<4294967295u;d++)int number;
}
```

This simple method will run a dumb loop the max value of uint32_t many times

and when I call:

```
speedTest<uint32_t>();
```

the software takes an average of 8.15 seconds but when I call:

```
speedTest<uint64_t>();
```

the software takes an average of 10.35 seconds.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Incrementing a 64-bit variable in 32-bit code takes more work.  Especially when you profile code that hasn't been optimized, a fairly pointless exercise.

Comment: If you enable optimizations both will take 0.0s

Comment: It's not pointless if I learn something. Something I didn't take into account was that the compilation of the software is 32bit which I recognize right away is an issue. I'm also very new to optimizations with g++, zch can you elaborate or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code in your question is not C.

Comment: Whoever fixed that discrepancy (tag) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some possible reasons:

- Larger data types require more memory bandwidth in general
- Even if that loop counter is kept inside a register, the CPU is probably taking more time to do calculations with large values, especially, if it needs multiple registers (e.g. if your CPU has just 32bit wide registers)
- The compiler would need to emit extra machine instructions to emulate any type not directly supported by the CPU
- It also depends on optimization. Such a loop without side effects could be optimized out completely, regardless of `int number;` (could just be `for(T d=0;d<4294967295u;d++);`)

You could continue your investigation/exercise by providing some assembly.

Comment: I failed to recognize that the g++ compilation will be 32bit regardless of the platform I made it on. I don't know how to specify a 64bit build yet (still learning gcc/g++)

Comment: But I do have a question about your first bullet. Correct me if I'm wrong but if this were compiled to operate as a 64bit application it wouldn't matter if the variable were uint32_t or uint64_t since either way the bandwidth passed around will always be 64bit

Comment: On a 64bit platform, it should default to 64bits. However, you can pass following compiler args: `-m32`, `-m64`. The bit width of a platform primarily designates the available address space, not values. However, to handle addresses efficiently, there are also according registers. An `int` can be 32 or 64bits, whereas the C99 types with explicit width don't vary.

Comment: @Parad0x13 The x86-64 64-bit instruction set allows to manipulate 32-bit registers directly, and with shorter opcodes than for 64-bit registers.

Comment: I see, more research on my part is needed then since I clearly did not understand how things worked. I assumed (for instance) that on a 64 bit processor all registers were 64bit

Comment: Another, related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8948918/1175253 | 
AMD64 Register layout: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Architectural_features

Comment: Thanks Sam, research will be accomplished and your insight is greatly appreciated