# Conversion from eax to rax register

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers

In the following code:

```
!6    movl $5, %ebx
```

The register shows the value of:

```
rbx 0x0000000000000005
```

Does `ebx` automatically convert to `rdx` on a 64-bit architecture? Is writing `ebx` "wrong" or is more-or-less an alias for `rdx` when on that architecture? Is there any significant difference between the two?

For example, for me they both produce the same in gdb:

```
>>> p $rbx
$3 = 5
>>> p $rax
$4 = 1
>>> p $eax
$5 = 1
>>> p $ebx
$6 = 5
```

Comment: I updated Employed Russian's answer; it left out the important detail that writing EBX *does* zero-extend into the full RBX, so yes `mov $5, %ebx` is what compilers use instead of `mov $5, %rbx` for values from 0..2^32 - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or is more-or-less an alias for rdx when on that architecture?

The `$ebx` is an alias to the lower 32 bits of the full `$rbx` register (there is *no* actual `ebx` register).

> Does ebx automatically convert to rdx on a 64-bit architecture?

No, but writing to EBX zero-extends into RBX.  (Not RDX, I assume B vs. D is a typo).  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)

So yes, `mov $5, %ebx` does *exactly* the same thing as `mov $5, %rbx` but is more efficient (fewer machine-code bytes).  Some assemblers (not GAS) will even optimize one to the other for you.

For example:

```
   mov   $-1, %rbx         # RBX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
   mov   %ebx, %ecx        # RCX = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
   dec   %ebx              # RBX = 0x00000000FFFFFFFE
```

> Is writing ebx "wrong"

Depends (see below).  Usually it's an optimization if you don't need to work with 64-bit quantities.  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64)

> Is there any significant difference between the two?

Yes. Of the following assembly instructions, only one will compile:

```
movq $0x12345678ABCD, $rbx
movq $0x12345678ABCD, $ebx
```