# How to isolate byte and word array elements in a 64-bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sign-extension, zero-extension

I can tell this is a super simple problem but I have yet to figure it out. Basically, I just want to be able to take one element an array and add and subtract some numbers from it using registers and then put the result into my result variable.

```
segment .data
  a      dw  4, 234, -212
  b      db  112, -78, 50
  result dq  0
segment .text       
  global main
main:
  mov   rax, [a]
```

I know the solution has something to do with offsets and indexing, but I don't get how I am supposed to be able to get just one array element into a register.

What can I do?

Comment: Use the proper sized register (or convert sizes) with the proper offset. E.g. `mov ax, [a+2]` would load `234` and `mov al, [b+1]` would load `-78`.

Comment: For example, use `movzx rax, word ptr [a]` (MASM syntax) or a similar expression to get the value `4` from the array and fill the upper bits of RAX with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat your values as signed, you want [`movsx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd).  Assuming NASM syntax:

```
default rel
; ... declarations and whatever    

    movsx   rax, word [a + 1*2]    ; a is an array of dw = words
    movsx   rcx, byte [b + 1*1]    ; b is an array of db = bytes

    add     rax, rcx
    mov     [result], rax         ; result is a qword
```

(MASM or GNU .intel_syntax would use `word ptr` instead of `word`, just add `ptr` to the size specifier for the memory operand.)

The `1` can be a register like `[a + rsi*2]` or `[b + rsi]` so you can easily loop over your arrays.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)

I wrote `1*2` instead of just 2 to indicate that it's index 1 (the 2nd array element), scaled by the element size.  The assembler will evaluate the constant expression and just use the same (RIP-relative) addressing mode it would for `[a]` but with a different offset.

If you need it to work in position-independent code (where you can't use a `[disp32 + register]` addressing mode with a 32-bit absolute address for the symbol), `lea  rdi, [a]` (RIP-relative LEA) first and do `[rsi + rsi*2]`.

---

If you wanted zero-extension, you'd use `movzx`

```
    movzx   eax, word [a + 1*2]    ; a is an array of dw = words
    movzx   ecx, byte [b + 1*1]    ; b is an array of db = bytes
    ; word and byte zero-extended into 64-bit registers:
    ; explicitly to 32-bit by MOVZX, and implicitly to 64-bit by writing a 32-bit reg

    ; add     eax, ecx              ; can't overflow 32 bits, still zero-extended to 64
    sub     rax, rcx              ; want the full width 64-bit signed result 
    mov     [result], rax         ; result is a qword
```

If you knew the upper bits of your full result would always be zero, just use EAX (32-bit operand-size) except at the end.  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64)

This code corresponds to C like

```
static  uint16_t a[] = {...};
static  uint8_t b[] = {...};
static  int64_t result;

void foo(){
    int64_t rax = a[1] - (int64_t)b[1];
    result = rax;    // why not just return this like a normal person instead of storing?
}
```

**Speaking of which, you can look at compiler output [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A//+actually+making+them+static+will+optimize+away+if+not+other+functions+in+this+file+touch+them.%0A++uint16_t+a%5B%5D+%3D+%7B4,+234,+212%7D%3B%0A++uint8_t+b%5B%5D+%3D+%7B112,+78,+50%7D%3B%0A++int64_t+result%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()%7B%0A++++int64_t+rax+%3D+a%5B1%5D+-+(int64_t)b%5B1%5D%3B%0A++++result+%3D+rax%3B++++//+why+not+just+return+this+like+a+normal+person+instead+of+storing%3F%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:46.096920342406875,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:53.90307965759314,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) and see these instructions and addressing modes.**

---

Note that `mov al, [b + 1]` would load a byte and *merge* it into the low byte of RAX.

**You normally don't want this; `movzx` is the normal way to load a byte** in modern x86.  Modern x86 CPUs decode x86 to RISC-like internal uops for register renaming + Out-of-Order execution.  `movzx` avoids any false dependency on the old value of the full register.  It's analogous to ARM `ldrb`, MIPS `lbu`, and so on.

Merging into the low byte or word of RAX is a weird CISC thing that x86 can do but RISCs can't.

You can safely *read* 8-bit and 16-bit registers (and you need to for a word store) but generally avoid writing partial registers unless you have a good reason, and you understand the possible performance implications  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)).  e.g. you've xor-zeroed the full destination ahead of cmp + `setcc al`.