# Why does GCC chose dword movl to copy a long shift count to CL?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, micro-optimization

In the third chapter of *Computer System: A Programmer's Prespective*, an example program is given when talking about shift operations:

```c
long shift_left4_rightn(long x, long n)
{
    x <<= 4;
    x >>= n;
    return x;
}
```

And its assembly code is as follows (reproducible with [GCC10.2 `-O1` for x86-64 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q5s5fs).  `-O2` schedules the instructions in a different order but still uses `movl` to ECX):

**shift_left4_rightn:**
　　**endbr64**
　　**movq　　　%rdi, %rax**　　　　*Get x*
　　**salq　　　$4, %rax**　　　　　　*x <<= 4*
　　**movl　　　%esi, %ecx**　　　　*Get n*
　　**sarq　　　%cl, %rax**　　　　　*x >>= n*
　　**ret**

I wonder why the assembly code of getting n is `movl　%esi, %ecx` instead of `movq　%rsi, %rcx` since `n` is a quad-word.

On the other hand, `movb　%sil, %cl` might be more suitable if the optimation is considered, since the shift amount only use the single-byte register element `%cl` and those higher bits are all ignored.

As a result, I really fail to figure out the reason for using "**movl　%esi, %ecx**" when dealing with long integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GCC realizes that upper bits are ignored by `sar`.
Then `movl` is the natural consequence of applying two simple optimization rules:

- Avoid writing partial registers (i.e. 8 or 16-bit, where writing merges into the old value instead of zero-extending).  [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502) - For various reasons across different microarchitectures, including in this case a false dependency on the old value of RCX.
- [Prefer 32-bit operand size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64) because it's the default in x86-64 machine code, not needing any prefixes. And it's at least as fast as any other operand-size for any instruction.

Fun fact: even if the arg had been `uint8_t`, compiles would still hopefully use `movl %esi, %ecx`.  You'd think reading a wider register when the arg value is only in SIL could create a partial-register stall, but an unofficial extension to the x86-64 System V calling convention is that [callers should zero or sign extend narrow args to at least 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539).  So we can assume it was written with at least a 32-bit operation.

The specific downsides of some other choices:

- `movq %rsi, %rcx` - waste of a REX prefix (code-size downside).
- `movb %sil, %cl` - writes a partial register, and still needs a REX prefix to access SIL.
- `movzbl %sil, %ecx` - code size: 2-byte opcode, and needs a REX to read SIL.  Also, AMD CPUs only do mov-elimination (zero latency) for `movl` / `movq`, not movzx.
- `movw %si, %cx` - zero advantages, needs an operand-size prefix and writes a partial register.
- `movzwl %si, %ecx` - Tied with `movq` for code-size, but defeats mov-elimination even on Intel CPUs.

---

Fun fact: if we pad with a dummy arg so `n` arrives in RDX, GCC still chooses `movl %edx, %ecx`, even though `movb %dl, %cl` is the same code-size (no REX needed to access DL).  So yes, GCC is definitely avoiding byte operand-size.

Fun fact 2: Clang unfortunately does waste a REX on `movq`, missing this optimization.  https://godbolt.org/z/6GWhMd

But if we make the count arg `unsigned char`, clang and GCC do both use `movl` instead of `movb`, fortunately.  https://godbolt.org/z/e95WP8

Answer (score 0):

When possible, compilers prefer 32-bit registers over 64-bit registers, because using 64-bit registers requires an additional 'REX' prefix byte.

The same applies selection of the lowest byte of `rsi\esi` register, which is not available in the 32-bit encoding, thus requires a prefix. As Peter Cordes commented, compilers generally avoid using 8-bit registers due to time penalties called [partial register stalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41574531/1716339), internal to how the CPUs can detect dependency chains, out-of-order execute and rename registers.

Comment: Pretty sure GCC avoids SIL because it avoids partial-register shenanigans whenever possible, and would make the same choice if that arg had arrived in EDX.

Comment: No partial-register stall is expected here. `movb` would write a partial register, but no read of the full register is expected.  (It's a call-clobbered reg in a leaf function).  So partial-register renaming would actually make that totally fine. The problem isn't partial-register *stalls*, it's on CPUs that *don't* rename the low-byte separately from the full register (Intel Haswell and later, and any non-Intel).  There you'll have a false dependency on the full register.  Avoiding this kind of false dep is why Intel P6 family did partial-register renaming, and it would work great here.

Comment: (But as a general rule, compilers may well not analyze that carefully and just avoid writing 8-bit regs whenever possible, even with `-mtune=nehalem`.)