# Why does gcc use %esi register as an 8-byte function parameter

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

To learn assembly I am viewing the assembly generated by GCC using the -S command for some simple C programs on Linux.

I write a C function `foo.c`

```
long shift_left4_rightn(long x, long n)
{
        x <<= 4;
        x >>= n;
        return x;
}
```

When I run `gcc -Og -S foo.c`

I got `foo.s` . Below is the part about this function

```
shift_left4_rightn:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        salq    $4, %rax
        movl    %esi, %ecx
        sarq    %cl, %rax
        ret
```

The function parameter x uses the register %rdi, which is normal. What confuses me is why the other parameter n uses the register %esi instead of %rsi. What am I missing? What would happen if I replace `movl %esi, %ecx` with `movq %rsi, %rcx`.

Comment: Only the lower 8 bits are actually used for anything (actually only the lower 6 bits), so it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can try it and see what happens by editing the `.s` output, then build and single-step it with GDB.  (Be careful with this approach in general, though: in asm it's often possible for things to happen to work, depending on details of the caller they're not supposed to).  But yes, more literally translating C to asm by using a 64-bit `mov` would be 100% fine.  x86 shift instructions mask the count anyway, so high bits are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior if you try to shift by more than the number of bits in a value. If `long` is 64 bits, this means that the maximum possible value of `n` is `64`, even though it's declared as a `long`. So we don't need all 8 bytes of `n`, the low 4 bytes are enough. In fact, even `%sil` (1 byte) would be OK, but maybe there's a performance reason why it prefers `%esi`.

I think it would still work if you use `%rsi`.

Comment: The probable reason is that 32-bit operations often have the shortest opcodes.

Comment: @ElderBug no, 8-bit and 32-bit instructions usually have the same length. It's just that 32-bit versions avoid the partial register update

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, avoiding partial registers is why GCC chooses 32-bit in this case.  But it's also shorter: `mov %sil, %cl` would need a REX prefix.  (But as you say, not because of the opcode.)  There's actually already a canonical Q&A for this: [Why does GCC chose dword movl to copy a long shift count to CL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63571651) based on the same example code (apparently from CS:APP)

Comment: 32-bit operand-size is shorter than 64, though, if that's what @ElderBug was getting at.  (But again, that's due to not needing a REX prefix, not strictly the opcode itself.)  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38303333)

Comment: As mentioned, I meant that 32-bit ops will often (maybe always ? I'm not sure) have the shortest instruction size, including prefixes. 8-bit can have the same shortest size but not here.

Comment: @ElderBug: Yes, 32-bit operand-size has encodings that are at least as small as any other operand-size (in 32 and 64-bit mode), except for stuff like `test r/m8, imm8` (because there is no `test r/m32, sign_extended_imm8`), and for the AL, imm special cases like 2-byte `cmp $1, %al`.   [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)