# How to swap bytes in 64bit Registers using NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, endianness

I've been searching for an equivalent bswap instruction for 64 bit, but I did not find anything yet.

Let's say I have the following in a register **RAX**:

```
mov rax, 0x666E69
```

After swaping the values the register **RAX** should contain the following:

```
rax = 0x696E6600
```

I already tried with shl, shr, rol, and ror but nothing worked. Can you please help me ? Thank you.

Comment: If you wanted to swap 64 bits I would expect input 666E69h to result in 696E6600_00000000h. Which one is it?

Comment: If you can't do it in one instruction, then use more than one instruction.

Comment: @ecm the one you provided is correct, I made a mistake I used as a example bwsap with a 32bit register eax

Comment: @ErikEidt can you give me more details please ?

Comment: [edit] your question to fix the expected input and output. Anyway, `bswap` works with 32 and 64 bit too. Does neither of those produce the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

`bswap eax` will reverse the low 4 bytes of RAX, zeroing the top 4 bytes of RAX [as part of writing the result to EAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  **32-bit operand-size is always available, you don't *have* to use 64-bit operand-size in 64-bit mode.**  Look at any compiler output for code using `int` and you'll see 32-bit registers being used.  See also [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64)

In fact `bswap r32` is faster (1 uop, 1c latency) than `bswap r64` (2 uops, 2c latency) on mainstream Intel (including even Ice Lake)  https://uops.info/

The low 4 bytes forward and reverse are
`00 66 6E 69` input
`69 6E 66 00` 32-bit [bswap](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bswap) result

That gives the result you say you want, for this input.  If you have some other requirement for larger inputs with non-zero high halves, say so.  (If you have SSSE3, you can do an arbitrary byte shuffle on an XMM register; worth considering if a `bswap r32` or `bswap r64` isn't what you want.