# Is using small types useless for performance (speed and memory)?

Tags: optimization, types, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I recently worked on a project in Rust with a protocol using less than 8 bits for some parts.

I figure out that using a 4bits integer doesn't improve performance or memory as using an 8bits integer.
Using arbitrary size is only arbitrary in terms of API, not in storage.

I saw that 64-bit processors use bus that is 64-bit wide, Is that mean using types smaller than 64-bits doesn't increase performance?

Comment: By the way I've found that, as a rule of thumb, any article or QA answer etc that says such things as "64-bit processors use a 64-bit bus" (*which* bus?), is probably not talking about contemporary hardware and its real-life properties.

Comment: The processor is almost certainly interacting with the cache to do byte loads/stores if that's what the program says to do.  The cache is inside the processor, and the bus is what the cache  uses to access main memory.  As Peter says, small sizes help when using larger data structures like arrays; however by contrast, parameter passing, for example, is mostly done in registers so the choice of int vs. char doesn't matter much as these values are not necessarily even going thru the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrower types are good for arrays, to reduce cache misses (and bandwidth for accessing multiple elements consecutively).  And for structs to pack more together, so a single struct fits in one cache line instead of multiple if there are many different integer elements or some small arrays.  Cache footprint and memory bandwidth can be a big deal even though total size usually isn't.

But usually 1 byte is the smallest it's worth considering, because CPUs can do that for free or nearly, but packing bits or bitfields inside bytes takes more work to load / modify / store the containing byte or word.

There are exceptions to this rule, like with a bitmap (array of bits), which is useful for some things.  Being able to check 64 bits at once instead of just 8 bytes at once (with an 8-byte register) for being non-zero is useful if users of your array will want to search for the next set bit.

For non-array local variables, usually you want to use something all CPUs can do efficiently, like C's `int` / `unsigned`, or Rust's `i32` / `u32`.  Compilers will often keep these in registers, where a variable takes up a whole register regardless of size, and narrower might mean the compiler has to use extra instructions to truncate to 8 or 16 bits.  (Or on x86, use byte or word operand-size, which can sometimes be less efficient.)

---

Related: [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory) - hardware *can* in fact load/store single bytes efficiently.  Sometimes with a bit of extra cost for a byte store vs. a 32 or 64-bit store, but if you write multiple bytes next to each other, most such CPUs can coalesce into one commit to cache.

Also related for x86-64: 32-bit operand-size is the most efficient in code-size, and also performance for division.  [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303333/the-advantages-of-using-32bit-registers-instructions-in-x86-64)